# How to limit the selected number of child nodes in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

When I click on the parent node, I need to disable some certain number of selected child nodes.

```
if ($("#chart-type-dd").val() === "Floating Bubbles") {
    if ($('#disaggregate-by').val() == "Description") {
        $("#treeElement").bind("change_event", function (e, d) {
            var node = d.args[0]
            $("#treeElement").set_type("disabled", "#node")
        });
    }
}



$('#' + containerRef).jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": datum
    },
        "dataType": "text",
        "check_callback": true,
        "types": {
        "#": {
            "name": "YO",
                "valid_children": ["folder", "file"]
        },
            "root": {
            "icon": false,
                "valid_children": ["folder", "file"]
        },
            "folder": {
            "icon": false,
                "valid_children": ["folder", "file"]
        },
            "file": {
            "icon": false,
                "valid_children": []
        },
            "types": {
            "disabled": {
                "check_node": false,
                    "uncheck_node": false
            }
        }
    },
        "checkbox": {
        "real_checkboxes": "true"
    },
        "plugins": [
        "unique", "sort", "types", "checkbox"]
});
}
```

Comment: Describe what you have tried so far, including the relevant code snippets.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mujg3b1k/ @Risadinha

Comment: Included the externally-referenced code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you question lacks a lot of information, check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3k7t2v4/).

It basically finds all children of a particular element, and then iterate over all of them adding them a new class.

```
var children = document.getElementById("toto").children;
var limit = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    if (!children[i]) return;
    children[i].classList.add("off");
}
```

Once the limit you defined is reached, or if there is no more child before the limit is reached, loop stops.

Hope it helps.

Br.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `conditionalselect` plugin a try. It is described in the docs - it provides a callback that is executed every time a node is about to be selected and you can prevent the selection.